# Can I prevent SQL Server Management Studio 2017 prefixing scripts with "Scripting Parameters"?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2017

Whenever I modify an object from within SSMS 2017, it always includes a "Scripting Parameters" section like this:

```
/*    ==Scripting Parameters==

    Source Server Version : SQL Server 2014 (12.0.4522)
    Source Database Engine Edition : Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise Edition
    Source Database Engine Type : Standalone SQL Server

    Target Server Version : SQL Server 2017
    Target Database Engine Edition : Microsoft SQL Server Standard Edition
    Target Database Engine Type : Standalone SQL Server
*/
```

Does anyone know of a setting to turn this off? It's not a show stopper, but it is annoying me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Ken Van Hyning (t=@sqltoolsguy) Engineering Manager for SQL Server Client Tools - this should be fixed in v17.3

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Will keep a look out for it.